# Outlook 2013, how to search for messages sent or received on, say, saturdays

Tags: microsoft-outlook, search, microsoft-outlook-2003

I tried "sent:saturday" in the search box, but it didn't show me any results. I have messages sent and received on a saturday.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't possible as far as I know without writing a large chunk of VBA which would enumerate all messages and their sent date and then convert the date to a day and return a list of emails which matched saturay.

The closest you can probably get is to use advanced find (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>), go to the advanced tab and start creating rules for each saturday you want to search.

If you do decide to go down the VBA route, please post whatever code you manage and we will try to help where we can.

Comment: Thanks. I think I'll have to go with the VBA option, but I found the mail that I wanted. I'll try the VBA code when I find some time.

Answer (score 1):

I got a solution, go to your sent box, type from:"<your name/alias>" and type Saturday/Sunday or name of whatever day you want to search the emails sent on that day of the week. to ensure the accuracy of results (or to avoid any other noise) turn off the grouping of conversations from view menu temporarily (short cut - alt + V + Y1 + H). This is my first response if you find it useful please thumps up.
e.g. from:"Gaurav Loya" from:"Test.Alias@Sample.Test"